# how to avoid oom killer for coding with python

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I wrote a crawler coding with python, but it often leads to oom killer, oom killer makes linux freeze and I can not connect to os via ssh. I also write a script to protect memory, if memory
usage exceeds 80% [memusage = (MemTotal - MeMFree - Buffers - Cached)/MeMTotal], restart crawler. but it seems not work. so my question is that how to avoid oom killer, and even if oom killer happens, is there something method to avoid freeze whole opertion system?

when oom-killer happens, screen prints information below, who can explain to me these information?

```
ve:okB present:16256kB Pages_scanned:173280531 all_unreclaimable? yes
[9132.468227] lowmem_reserve[]: 0  829  829  829
[9132.468403]Normal free:3628kB  min:3648kB  low:4568kB  high:5472kB  active:614280kB  inactive:22508kB  present:849376kB  pages_scanned:1415839762 all_unreclaimable? yes
[9132.468713] lowmem_reserve[]: 0  0  0  0
[9132.468883]DMA: 0.4kB  1.8kB  1*16kB  1,32kB  0*64kB  0*128kB  1*256kB  0*512kB  1*1024kB  1*2048kB  0*4096kB = 3384kB
[9132.469286]Normal:7.4kB 5*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3620kB
[9132.469674]Swap cache:add 0, delete 0, find 0/0, race 0+0
[9132.469825]Frees swap = 0kB
[9132.469905]Total swap = 0kB
[9132.469986]Free swap:        0kB
[9132.472289]218112 pages of RAM
[9132.472386]0 pages of HIGHMEM
[9132.472469]44668 reserved pages
[9132.472553]5732 pages shared
[9132.472634]0 pages swap cached
[9132.472760]0 pages dirty
[9132.472837]0 pages writeback
[9132.472919]874 pages mapped
[9132.472999]3343 pages slab
[9132.473082]392 pages pagetables
```

Comment: Either your machine have very low memory or you must be having a bad memory leak in your program. Fix that and you won't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

As i understand you have no swap partition or disable it, try add swap.
With no swap, it has no way to evict dirty pages from memory and system can freeze.

Answer (score 2):

The OOM killer is one of the strangest parts of unix to me, never seems to go after the process with all the memory.

The solution is to not have your python process consume too much memory. You can temporarily alleviate the problem by installing more memory.

However, the long-term solution is to write your crawler so that it doesn't eat all your memory.

Without seeing your code, we can only guess at where all the memory is going.

Comment: The OOM killer will kick in only if you're *really* sucking up memory. Are you sure that you need to in your app?